# Creating instances of a class during Rails startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, instance

I'm trying to create multiple instances of a class while Rails loads, and to keep those instances available. (I'm loading the data from a YAML file, but I've abstracted away that detail for this question.) I have a non-ActiveRecord model with an `instantiate` class method that loads the data. When I call `instantiate` from `config.after_initialize` and/or from a custom initializer, the instances are created, but by the time `rails console` finishes loading, they are gone. Where can I instantiate the data so that it will be available within rails console (and the server)?

```
# app/models/test.rb
class Test
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name

  class << self
    include Enumerable

    def each
      ObjectSpace.each_object(self).each do |object|
        yield object
      end
      self
    end

    def find_by_name(input)
      find { |object| object.name.to_s == input.to_s }
    end

    def instantiate
      new(name: 'Alice')
      new(name: 'Bob')
    end
  end

  def initialize(*parameters)
    super(*parameters)
    freeze
  end

  delegate :to_s, to: :name
end


# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.after_initialize do
      p "Test instances before after_initialize: #{Test.count}"
      Test.instantiate
      p "Test instances after after_initialize: #{Test.count}"
    end
  end
end


# config/initializer/test_initializer.rb
p "Test instances before test_initializer: #{Test.count}"
Test.instantiate
p "Test instances after test_initializer: #{Test.count}"


$ rails console
"Test instances before test_initializer: 2"
"Test instances after test_initializer: 4"
"Test instances before after_initialize: 0"
"Test instances after after_initialize: 2"
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
irb(main):001:0> Test.count
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> Test.instantiate
=> #<Test:0x007fad2204d8b0 @name="Bob">
irb(main):003:0> Test.count
=> 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the solution that you posted. Since you are in control of the instantiation process, you don't need to use the `ObjectSpace` at all. If you want the `Test` class to remember just two instances created in the `#instantiate` method, you could something like this:

```
class Test
  @objects = []

  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name

  class << self
    include Enumerable

    def each
      if block_given?
        objects.each { |o| yield o }
      else
        objects.to_enum
      end
    end

    def find_by_name(input)
      find { |object| object.name.to_s == input.to_s }
    end

    def instantiate
      objects << new(name: 'alice')
      objects << new(name: 'Bob')
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :objects
  end

  def initialize(*parameters)
    super(*parameters)
    freeze
  end

  delegate :to_s, to: :name
end
```

If you want the `Test` class to remember all the objects that were instantiated. You could change the lines:

```
...
    def instantiate
      new(name: 'alice')
      new(name: 'Bob')
    end
  end

  def initialize(*parameters)
    super(*parameters)
    freeze
    self.class.objects << self
  end
...
```

Comment: Thanks. See my revised answer for how I iterated on your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby garbage collector removes the instances from the memory. There exists no direct links that references the newly created instances, so Ruby deems them unnecessary.

You can try this by adding:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.after_initialize do
      GC.disable # Disable garbage collector
      p "Test instances before after_initialize: #{Test.count}"
      Test.instantiate
      p "Test instances after after_initialize: #{Test.count}"
    end
  end
end
```

But disabling garbage collector is not a good idea. If you would reference the instances somehow they will not get sweeped and they will be available after the startup through references.

Answer (score 0):

[**rewritten** / **updated code**]

@Laura Paakkinen thanks very much for your answer. You're correct that the underlying problem was garbage collection of instances that were not referenced. And, you were also correct that since my class is doing the instantiating, it can simply keep an instance variable to track all members of the class.

Unlike your approach below, I decided to add memoization via an `all` method. In particular, I was finding that on running `reload!` in rails console, the contents of the Criteria class would be erased. My solution is to add a test in `all` and to instantiate if the [memoized](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/) instance variable is empty or nil. This also means that the initializer is no longer necessary, as the Class now instantiates on first use. Note that `each` calls `all`, and via the Enumerable mixin, all other class methods invoke `each`.

Thanks again for your thoughtful replies, which brought me to a much better answer.

```
class Test
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :value

  class << self
    include Enumerable

    def [](key)
      instantiate if @test.blank?
      @test[key.to_sym]
    end

    def all
      instantiate if @test.blank?
      @test.values
    end

    def each
      all.each do |object|
        yield object
      end
      self
    end

    def keys
      map(&:name)
    end

    def instantiate
      @test = {}
      @test[:Alice] = new(name: 'Alice', value: 1)
      @test[:Bob] = new(name: 'Bob', value: 2)
    end
  end

  # Instance Methods

  def initialize(*parameters)
    super(*parameters)
    freeze
  end

  delegate :to_s, to: :name
end
```

Comment: Yeah, Rails removes all the autoloaded classes with `reload!` in development. Hm, another solution for this issue, if don't need the reloading functionality for this class, is to add it to the`config.autoload_once_paths` in `config/application.rb`. That way it is excluded from reloading. See more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html